# Calculated columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, date, aggregate

I have the following dataframe

[image: dataframe illustration]

Code for dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Car Type': ['Compact']*9 + ['Economy'],
                  'Supplier':['Alamo','Enterprise','Budget','Nation', 'Avis','Payless','Payless','Payless','E-ZRent-a-Car','E-ZRent-a-Car'],
                  'Total Price':[74]*3+[78,79,84,35,37,43,43],
                  'Location':['Altanta']*10,
                  'Pick-up Date':['Jun/12/2019']*6+['Jun/13/2019']*4,
                  'Date Accessed':['06-11-2019']*10})
```

I need to create a dataframe that would contain a list of unique combinations of "Supplier", "Car Type", "Pick-up Date", "Date Accessed" as well as the number of competitive offers and the best competitor price available 1-14 days prior to the "Pick-up Date".

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Do not post image of your data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557)

Answer (score 0):

To get unique combinations of the columns you described:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=["Supplier", "Car Type", "Pick-up Date", "Date Accessed"])
```

Comment: Thanks, this I have.  It is the second part (calculated columns) that I need help with.

Comment: See @Quang Hoang 's comment re: images.  Also provide sample output of what you'd expect the solution to look like.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

You need to filter your dataframe first, then sort by Total Price and drop duplicates.

```
df[(df['Pick-up Date'] - df['Date Accessed']) < pd.Timedelta(days=14)]\
 .sort_values('Total Price', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['Car Type', 'Supplier', 
                                                               'Pick-up Date', 'Date Accessed'])
```

Output:

```
  Car Type       Supplier  Total Price Location Pick-up Date Date Accessed
5  Compact        Payless           84  Altanta   2019-06-12    2019-06-11
4  Compact           Avis           79  Altanta   2019-06-12    2019-06-11
3  Compact         Nation           78  Altanta   2019-06-12    2019-06-11
0  Compact          Alamo           74  Altanta   2019-06-12    2019-06-11
1  Compact     Enterprise           74  Altanta   2019-06-12    2019-06-11
2  Compact         Budget           74  Altanta   2019-06-12    2019-06-11
8  Compact  E-ZRent-a-Car           43  Altanta   2019-06-13    2019-06-11
9  Economy  E-ZRent-a-Car           43  Altanta   2019-06-13    2019-06-11
7  Compact        Payless           37  Altanta   2019-06-13    2019-06-11
```